# How to automatically create a runtime folder with a systemd service or tmpfiles.d?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, python, socket

I'm trying to create a runtime folder at `/run/gunicorn` for some Gunicorn socket / PID files, which are for a Django application. I can get everything working if I manually create directories. However, I'm trying to make this a robust setup, and eventually use Ansible to automate everything.

I think I have 2 options, based on this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125286/whats-the-best-way-to-have-uwsgi-create-a-run-uwsgi-folder-on-reboot).

**Option 1 - RuntimeDirectory**

I think the first option is to use `RuntimeDirectory=` within my systemd service file, but I can't get it to create the folder. The service files contains:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn_django_test.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn_django daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=gunicorn
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn #This line is supposed to create a directory
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/django_test_pid
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant/webapps/django_venv/django_test
ExecStart=/vagrant/webapps/django_venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/django_test_pid --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/django_test_socket django_test.wsgi --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/django_test_error.log
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `systemctl start gunicorn_django_test.service`, the service fails to start. When I snip out the exec line, and run it manually, I get `Error: /run/gunicorn doesn't exist. Can't create pidfile.` If I create the `/run/gunicorn` folder manually, I can get things to work.

**Option 2 - tmpfiles.d**

The second option is to use `tmpfiles.d` to have a folder created on boot, ready for the pid / socket files. I've tried this file:

```
#/etc/tmpfiles.d/gunicorn.conf
d /run/gunicorn 0755 gunicorn www-data -
```

This creates a directory, but it is quickly deleted somehow, and by the time I start the service, the folder isn't available.

I can manually add some PreExec `mkdir` commands into the service file, but I'd like to get to the bottom of why RuntimeDirectory / tmpfiles.d aren't working. Thanks.

*Versions / Info:
Ubuntu 16.04 Server / systemd 229 / Gunicorn 19.7.1 / runtime dir = /run*

Comment: It's something to do with group permissions in the /run/ folder. I can create a 0755 folder with the group as `www-data`, but I need the folder to be group writeable, so both the Nginx user and the Gunicorn user can access the socket file. In order to do that, I need sudo-level permissions. For some reason, `sudo systemctl... etc` isn't passing the sudo permissions to the service.

Comment: i'll bet it's trying to create the directory with the uid from `User=` and failing.  try adding `PermissionsStartOnly=true`.  see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207493/222377

Comment: hmm.  actually i'll bet it's failing because the runtime directory is made but isn't `/run/gunicorn`.  it's probably `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gunicorn` which might resolve to `/run/user/$UID/gunicorn` for the `gunicorn` user UID.  (same question, [next answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207494/222377).)

Comment: Are you trying to use the same directory for multiple Gunicorn instances? You could be running into this [related issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5394)>

Comment: Your **Option 2** would have worked. However, the `tmpfiles.d` and `RuntimeDirectory=...` definitions are not compatible. You should not have both turned on at the same time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I added in `PermissionsStartOnly=True` and set a runtime folder per service, as suggested. I also added `0` to the start of the folder mode.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn_django daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=True
User=gunicorn
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn_django
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0775
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn_django/django_test_pid
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant/webapps/django_venv/django_test
ExecStart=/vagrant/webapps/django_venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn_django/django_test_pid --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn_django/django_test_socket django_test.wsgi --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/django_test_error.log
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It's now creating a folder with the correct permissions.

```
drwxrwxrw-  2 gunicorn www-data   40 Mar 30 07:11 gunicorn_django/
```

Thanks @quixotic and @mark-stosberg

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I had two services using same `RuntimeDirectory` (`isc-dhcp-server` and `isc-dhcp-server6`), but I configured only one to work. So when the second one died, its runtime directory got removed, making it a problem for the first service.